# checkbox from datagridview to textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, checkbox, textbox

A new issue !!

I have a checkbox column in the datagridview and also a column named "partqty" which displays the quantity of materails available.. I would want that when the user checks on the checkbox, the quantities of checked rows should be added and displayed in the textbox..

I tired something like this.. But it displays 0(zero) in the textbox.. Please help..

```
Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

        'For Each _rw As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
        '    If _rw.Cells(0).Value = True Then

        Dim totalSum As Integer

        For i As Integer = 0 To HemDatabase1DataSet5.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            totalSum += HemDatabase1DataSet5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("partqty")
        Next

        textBox5.Text = totalSum.ToString()
        '    End If
        'Next
    End Sub
```

Hey !! This is something i could think upon trying !! however, there is no error during compile time, but there is an error at runtime, which says :
Operator '+' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Boolean'

Here is the code i tried :

```
For Each _rw As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
            If _rw.Cells(0).Value = True Then

                Dim totalSum As Integer

                For i As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    totalSum += dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
                Next

                textBox5.Text = totalSum.ToString()
            End If
        Next
```

It gives error on this line :

```
totalSum += dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
```

Answer (score 2):

You first problem is that you are trying to add apples and oranges together.

In the line:

```
totalSum += dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
```

totalSum is an integer while the Value property of a DataGridView cell is of type `object`.

This is a similar problem to what you see when trying to use the DataTable except there your Item property is givin you a DBNull rather than an object back.

Here is the code that you want (I'm mainly a C# dev so the VB.Net might be lacking elegance but it works).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sum As Integer
    sum = 0

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim current As Integer

        If Integer.TryParse(row.Cells("OrderQty").Value.ToString, current) Then
            sum += current
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString
End Sub
```

Some things worth noting about that code:

- I use a For Each rather than a for. The two perform basically identically but I find the foreach more readable
- I use Integer.TryParse on the cell value before using it. This is safer than just casting the cell value directly.
- Rather then using column indexes which is a little fragile I use column names.

With your check on whether or not the checkbox is checked you can do something similar:

```
Boolean.TryParse(row.Cells("IsChecked").Value.ToString, cb)
```

---

One final point to note is that if you try to execute this code in the cellclick method of the DataGridView you will run into problems - the checkbox state is not committed until after the cellclick, so the most recently checked cell will not get added to your count. Instead you will want to handle the CellDirtyStateChanged and commit the edits, then doing the sum in the CellValueChanged handler.

To illustrate that try this code:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim sum As Integer
    sum = 0

    Dim cb As Boolean
    cb = False

    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name <> "IsChecked" Then
        Return
    End If


    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Boolean.TryParse(row.Cells("IsChecked").Value.ToString, cb) Then
            If cb Then
                Dim current As Integer

                If Integer.TryParse(row.Cells("OrderQty").Value.ToString, current) Then
                    sum += current
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString
End Sub
```

The sum will always lag one click behind (actually in VB.Net it appears to just nor really work - but I'm more a c# dev so that could be me missing something).

Instead you want:

```
Sub dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged( _
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

    If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub

' If a check box cell is clicked, this event handler disables  
' or enables the button in the same row as the clicked cell.
Public Sub dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "IsChecked" Then
        Dim sum As Integer
        sum = 0

        Dim cb As Boolean



        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Boolean.TryParse(row.Cells("IsChecked").Value.ToString, cb) Then
                If cb Then
                    Dim current As Integer

                    If Integer.TryParse(row.Cells("OrderQty").Value.ToString, current) Then
                        sum += current
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well i am putting this code in button click event.. Me too trying vb.net for the first time so thank you for all the explanation.. It helps in updating self.. I vl try this and revert soon.. Thanx again !! :)

Comment: Hey.. this doesn't seem to be working for me.. I am using this code and tried some modifications placed it in button click event !! Could you help me with modifying in my code ?? The second part of the code that i posted, is what i am working with !! Thank you.. :)

Comment: @Ruchi22 glad you have something working - it my answer ended up working for you please mark it as accepted, and if not, post as an answer what worked so others can use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked..

```
Dim iSselected As Boolean
        Dim CurrentCellValue As String
        Dim CumulativeSummer As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        With Me.dataGridView1
            For i = 0 To .RowCount - 1
                iSselected = .Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                CurrentCellValue = .Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
                If CurrentCellValue = "" Then CurrentCellValue = 0

                If iSselected = True Then
                    CumulativeSummer += Convert.ToInt32(CurrentCellValue)
                End If
            Next
        End With

        Me.textBox5.Text = CumulativeSummer
```

Thank u for your help !! :)